# How do I check if a jquery plugin is already initialized on a jquery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is code to destroy and initialize a jquery plugin cubeportfolio (I don't think this is specific to cubeportfolio).

```
jQuery('#some-grid').cubeportfolio('destroy');

jQuery('#some-grid').cubeportfolio(options);
```

If I want to re-initialize it, I first need to destroy it, which works fine if it already exists.

But I get an error if I try to destroy an instance, that does not already exists (which makes complete sense).

How can I check if cubeportfolio is already initialized on #some-grid?

Comment: Did you try `if(jQuery().cubeportfolio) {}` or if `(jQuery.fn.cubeportfolio) {}`  ?

Comment: I need to check it on each item, so on "#some-grid" in this case (as this is a simplified example. 

If I do a generic check like your comment, I don't see how that would work. 

My current workaround is a try catch around the destroy - which works - but is just not very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Boolean($('#some-grid').data('cubeportfolio'))
```

to check if an instance of `cubportfolio` already exists on the given element